# Cannot target #id as menu link?

Tags: routes

Drupal 6

How can i allow drupal to accept #idname as link? When I put # I cannot submit the form. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Problem is that Drupal tries to validate what you put in your menu, but cannot validate if element of that id exists on a target page. How open you feel about hacking contrib modules?

Answer (score 2):

You have five options.

1. Use the https://drupal.org/project/special_menu_items module
2. Do something like node/16#gohere (I'm not sure if you have a static page this is for)
3. Create a module to either edit a menu item or add one
4. Backport the https://drupal.org/project/void_menu module
5. Make your own module to do this :)

Sadly there is no way to do this by default.

Comment: Not to necro but special menu items module does not support #ID.